# Secret Recovery Phrase MetaMask - Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, metamask

I try to handle 12-words (Secret Recovery Phrase) to use for Login in my App. I try a lot of ways but it failed. Please help me if you have any idea about that. Thank you.

Comment: Hello! Did you later phone how to generate the 12 phrase?

Comment: I changed to generate the 12 phrases to private key to check

Comment: how can you post the idea here and explain, i will like to see what you have done... Thanks in advances